# Icon not showing when asked to

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

My app is blocking when i want to navigate to certain view, so i want to show a load icon. The problem is the icon never shows when expected. The view changes and i never see the icon, but if i go back the icon is there.

I tried using an async task to do the navigation, but the navigation doesn't work in a task, i guess.

Any suggestions or ideas?

XAML Code:

```
<UserControl xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/">
     <Grid>
          <Listbox ItemsSource={Binding ItemsList}>

          </Listbox>
          <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-550, 180, 0, 0">
              <fa:ImageAwesome Visibility="{Binding LoadingIcon, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                               Icon="Spinner" 
                               Spin="True" 
                               Canvas.Left="56" 
                               Canvas.Top="-17" />
          </Canvas>
     </Grid>
     <UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding NavigateToMainMenuCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel: ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged, INavigationAware
{
     public InicioContableViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager,
                                   IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        NavigateToMainMenuCommand = new DelegateCommand(NavigateToMainMenu);

        LoadingIcon = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public DelegateCommand NavigateToMainMenuCommand { get; private set; }

    private Visibility loadingIcon;
    public Visibility LoadingIcon
    {
        get
        {
            return loadingIcon;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref loadingIcon, value, nameof(LoadingIcon));
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(LoadingIcon));
        }
    }

    private void NavigateToMainMenu()
    {
        LoadingIcon = Visibility.Visible;

        string mainUri = nameof(SomeRoute.MainMenu);

        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(Regions.MainRegion, mainUri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Icon's properties, try to set Build Action to Resource.

Comment: Mm i don't know if i can do that. It's an awesome font icon loading purely with a xaml element.

Answer (score 0):

WPF uses the UI thread to do things like handle mouse movement, change icons when you tell it to and to switch out one view for another. All one thread.

When that thread is busy doing something then nothing is likely to change in your UI until it's finished.

Hence, if you tell it to make something visible AND navigate, you can well find all that happens visually is the navigation. Because it has no time to show your icon.

Try making your method async and giving it a little time:

```
private async void NavigateToMainMenu()
{
    LoadingIcon = Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Delay(60);

    string mainUri = nameof(SomeRoute.MainMenu);

    _regionManager.RequestNavigate(Regions.MainRegion, mainUri);
}
```

That task.delay should give it enough time to redraw a bit of ui.

If you need a loading icon and the thing you are navigating to is blocking then I suspect you have other problems.  It's likely that whatever this new view is doing to initialise should be asynchronous.  Maybe with data access etc on background threads.

Comment: As you said, that Delay allows the icon to be displayed! :D
Now the problem is that it freezes (it's a spinning circle) right after that delay. I used a profiler that showed me a UI Freeze due to a innecesary method call.
Already solved that and the UI Freeze no longer appears on the profiler, but i still get the icon freeze.
Tried to comment absolutely everything on the loading ViewModel, but it still freezes, so now I don't know where to aim, exactly.

I'll keep testing, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You may most likely make use of the functions:- InvalidateVisual() or UpdateLayout(). Those will force to redraw and may resolve your icon visibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

> My app is blocking when i want to navigate to certain view, so i want to show a load icon.

If the app is blocking, you cannot show the icon, because, you know, the app is blocked. You have to remove the blocking, that is, make navigation itself quick, and do whatever initialization asynchronously. The view you're navigating to may need stuff from a database or connection to a usb device, but it won't need it *immediately*. You can still query the database or whatever in the background after the view is shown.

show wait indicator-> navigate -> creates view model -> starts initializion task -> initialization completes -> hide wait indicator

Comment: Well, i disabled every initialization on the view i'm navigating to, but i'm still getting the UI freeze.

I'm a bit lost now, but i'll keep testing.